# Fancy word for weekly (contributor)

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a single noun similar in meaning to weekly contributor, but possibly of Latin or French root. (I am thinking that there has to be some version of French *semaine* used in English.)

The goal is to have a name for a participation badge on my website (think of Stack Overflow badge system). The badge would be awarded to those who participate in a weekly contest (for a number of weeks, without missing a week).

So, I am looking for a noun that describes somebody who does a weekly action. Ideally the noun would be derived from a verb to imply action. 
Something like "Weekly contributor" (or just "Weekly"), but in a single word and with a dash of grandeur and loftiness if possible.

**Edit: I would accept a word that just hints at "weekly". The contributor part would be nice but isn't a must.**

Comment: ***[Columnist](http://onelook.com/?w=columnist&ls=a&loc=home_ac_Columnist)***?

Comment: @Dan Bron, sorry, no, **Columnist** implies writing articles which is not the case for me. Thanks though!

Comment: [*regular*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/regular?s=t) (23). Not exactly foreign, nor particularly grandiose, but it seems to be the most accurate.

Comment: More cutesy (or anything else) than fancy, but if you’d run each contest for 7 weeks and require at least one contribution every 7 days for those 7 weeks you could call the contest “Septomania” and the badges (or at least those who earn them) “[Septomaniacs](http://www.paperbackswap.com/Encyclopedia-Seven-Marty-Cooling/book/1469974312/).”

Comment: How about just ***Marquis***?

Comment: @jxh What is your rationale for ***Marquis***?

Comment: @jxh with _**Marquis**_, what is the connection in meaning? There is no link to medieval nobility. :)

Comment: Weeks are a division of the lunar calendar. So you are clearly dealing with ***lunatics***, or ***loonies***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hebdomadaire means weekly in French. Maybe you could adapt that.

Comment: That sounds great, but that word is not (and was never) in usage in English, right?

Comment: @Edo: Yes that word, or at least *hebdomadal* is used in English quite frequently.

Answer (score 0):

**Sojourner** badge

A precedent is the **Sojourner** badge in Ingress
 (a popular multiplayer online game) which rewards players who play on consecutive days. Different colours represent levels; see  [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/210523) or [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/HXu8znkkjfv)

> A sojourner is a person who resides temporarily in a place. –[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sojourner)

Of course, stack exchange has 2 level badges [Enthusiast and Fanatic badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1675) but personally I think those names somewhat dull.

Comment: "Sojourner" sounds lofty enough, but how does the meaning relate to a weekly action (or a daily one such as in Ingress)?

Comment: Ingress use it as you have to go to a physical location to play, I think you could say that in your case, that place is somewhat metaphorical and represents being in the contest.